# ActionMailer Params not passing in preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails Action Mailer and when configring my first email, I get this error after visit http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/confirm_email:

undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
@user = params[:user]

My code:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def confirm_email
    @user = params[:user]
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end

class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def confirm_email
    UserMailer.with(user: User.first).confirm_email
  end
end
```

If I change code to this:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def confirm_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end

class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def confirm_email
    UserMailer.confirm_email(User.last)
  end
end
```

The preview class is located in test/mailers/preview, outside of the app folder.

I receive this:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

I cant understand, what I'm doing wrong?

My rails version is 6.0.3.5

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are positive you have at least one User record in your database, I would try the following, which is a mix of your attempts.

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def confirm_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end

class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def confirm_email
    UserMailer.with(user: User.first).confirm_email
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey ! I indeed had users in my db, the weird thing is I tried to send the email through the console, and it worked from there. And then, it started working again. So I have no Idea what triggered it but it just randomly started working at some point... Thanks for your help!